# Memcached not showing up in phpinfo()

Tags: php, linux, memcached, redhat

I've installed libmemcached and memcached pecl extension for php and for some reason it's not installing correctly? i've got memcached.so in /usr/lib64/php/ with the right permissions and libmemcache.so in /usr/local/lib/

Everything seemed to build correctly without error, and I restarted apache?

i also have the daemon installed.

I somehow easily got the Memcache class easily installed for php before, but I realized what i wanted was the Memcached (note the d) class. let me know if more info is needed!

EDIT: I previously had memcache (without the d) working in php so I know i was manipulating the correct php.ini!

EDIT 2: there WAS indeed an apache error!

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_json_encode in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Can you verify you have no errors in your apache error log?

Comment: Did you add the `extension=memcache.so` to the correct php.ini?

Comment: Yes there was an error. How do i fix the error is displays?

Comment: Simply fix the extension load order, json before memcached. (Using distribution packages, each extension have its configuration file starting with a number ensuring proper load order)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved it in centos5 using the yum installer instead of the pecl install memcached

THIS way --> yum install php-pecl-memcached

then, service httpd restart and it shows up in phpinfo()

Comment: hm, didn't think of this. I'll try this next time!

Comment: on debian: apt install php8.1-memcached

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar error few days ago. Instaling of new version(2.0) of memcached helped me.

```
yum -y install gcc-c++
wget http://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/0.50/+download/libmemcached-0.50.tar.gz
tar xzf libmemcached-0.50.tar.gz 
cd libmemcached-0.50
./configure 
make 
make install
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcached-2.0.0b2.tgz
pecl install memcached-2.0.0b2.tgz
echo 'extension=memcached.so' > /etc/php.d/memcached.ini
service php-fpm restart
cd ..
rm -r libmemcached-0.50*
rm -r memcached-
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same problem but after struggling with this for hours I manage to have PHP properly installed with Memcached on CentOS using the command bellow:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php-memcached
```

Test installation:

```
php -i | grep -i memcache
```

Should show something like:

```
/etc/php.d/50-memcached.ini
memcached
memcached support => enabled
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
memcached.default_binary_protocol => Off => Off
memcached.default_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.default_consistent_hash => Off => Off
memcached.serializer => igbinary => igbinary
memcached.sess_binary_protocol => On => On
memcached.sess_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => On => On
memcached.sess_consistent_hash_type => ketama => ketama
memcached.sess_lock_expire => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 5 => 5
memcached.sess_lock_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 150 => 150
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 150 => 150
memcached.sess_locking => On => On
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_persistent => Off => Off
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess.key. => memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => Off => Off
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers => Off => Off
memcached.sess_sasl_password => no value => no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username => no value => no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit => 0 => 0
memcached.store_retry_count => 2 => 2
Registered save handlers => files user memcached
```

Answer (score 0):

on debian:

```
 apt install php-memcached
```

or more specific:

```
apt install php8.2-memcached
```

also add `extension=memcached.so` in your `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini`

(note the final "d" at "mamcached")

Note, that this only works, if php8.2 is the latest php version, since the memcached.so is only installed in the latest extension dir – `/usr/lib/php/20220829/memcache.so` in the case of php8.2

Answer (score -2):

add

```
extension=memcache.so
```

in php.ini then restart apache